# google's speech2srt python code is showing error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to create srt file from my audio. Actually, I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBzp5xGSZ6o&ab_channel=GoogleCloudAPAC) for this. But when I am running the command `python3 speech2srt.py --storage_uri gs://subtitlingsc/en.wav` it is showing the following error:

```
Transcribing gs://subtitlingsc/en.wav ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speech2srt.py", line 152, in <module>
    main()
  File "speech2srt.py", line 146, in main
    subs = long_running_recognize(args)
  File "speech2srt.py", line 44, in long_running_recognize
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
TypeError: long_running_recognize() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

If someone could help in solving this!

Link for speech2srt.py [file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/blob/master/tutorials/speech2srt/speech2srt.py).

Comment: Provided the reason of your error. If the provided answer helps you somehow, consider accepting/upvoting

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to the fact that you are providing the arguments **config** and **audio** which should be both keyword arguments. To solve the problem, you can replace `client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)` with `client.long_running_recognize(config = config, audio = audio)`

As you can confirm [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/speech_v1/services.html#google.cloud.speech_v1.services.speech.SpeechAsyncClient.long_running_recognize), the function **long_running_recognize** has the definition below:

```
async long_running_recognize(
    request: google.cloud.speech_v1.types.cloud_speech.LongRunningRecognizeRequest = None, 
    *, 
    config: google.cloud.speech_v1.types.cloud_speech.RecognitionConfig = None, 
    audio: google.cloud.speech_v1.types.cloud_speech.RecognitionAudio = None, 
    retry: google.api_core.retry.Retry = <object object>, 
    timeout: float = None, 
    metadata: Sequence[Tuple[str, str]] = ()
    )
```

In **Python**, a function definition with arguments like (arg1, arg2, * , arg3, agr4, ...) means that only the arguments before the ***** can be provided as positional arguments. Being this the case, all the arguments after the ***** should be provided as keyword arguments.

As an example, lets create a function with the arguments I mentioned:

```
def function(arg1, arg2, * , arg3, agr4):
    pass
```

If I try to call this function as `function(1,2,3,4)`, it will fail because only two positional arguments are needed. To call it correctly I should provide two positional arguments and two keyword arguments therefore the correct call should be `function(1, 2, arg3 = 3, arg4 = 4)`